# Conflict between jquery-1.9.1.min.js and jquery.js/jquery.autocomplete.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used this autocomplete script http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html
There are included: jquery.js and jquery.autocomplete.js To work autocomplete these javascript are necessary

But I must use also jquery-1.9.1.min.js for autosave and other functions.

Unfortunately there is conflict between them. Autocomplete does not work with jquery-1.9.1.min.js (and jQuery 1.10.1 too).

If remove 1.9.1.min.js does not work other scripts.

Tried instead of one `$` to use `jQuery` and `jQuery.noConflict();` below `<script>` tag. 
Without success.

Tried to use other autocomplete script http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote but very slow response...

In jquery.js and jquery.autocomplete.js and there are ~ 3000 rows... seems not reasonable to experiment to find where is problem.

If someone faced with the same problem, please advice.

Here is code (if interested)....

```
 <input type="text" id="partner_name_or_description1" class="row_changed"/>
 <input type="text" id="partner_name_or_description2" class="row_changed"/>
 <input type="text" id="partner_name_or_description3" class="row_changed"/>
```

jquery-1.9.1.min.js is necessary for this javascript

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery('[id^="partner_name_or_description"]').each(function (index, partner_name_or_description) {
        var partner_name_or_description = partner_name_or_description.id.substring(27);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

jquery.js and jquery.autocomplete.js is necessary for below javascript

```
/**/function findValue(li) {
    /*if( li == null ) return alert("No match!");
    // if coming from an AJAX call, let's use the CityId as the value
    if( !!li.extra ) var sValue = li.extra[0];
    // otherwise, let's just display the value in the text box
    else var sValue = li.selectValue;
    alert("The value you selected was: " + sValue);*/
}

function selectItem(li) {
    findValue(li);
}

function formatItem(row) {
    return row[0] + " (id: " + row[1] + ")";
}

/*function lookupAjax(){
var oSuggest = $("#CityAjax")[0].autocompleter;
oSuggest.findValue();
return false;
}*/

/*function lookupLocal(){
var oSuggest = $("#CityLocal")[0].autocompleter;
oSuggest.findValue();
return false;
}*/


$("#partner_name_or_description1:input, #partner_name_or_description2:input, #partner_name_or_description3:input").autocomplete(
    "__autocomplete_source.php",
    {
        delay: 10,
        minChars: 2,
        matchSubset: 1,
        matchContains: 1,
        cacheLength: 10,
        onItemSelect: selectItem,
        onFindValue: findValue,
        formatItem: formatItem,
        autoFill: true
    }
);
```

Comment: Use jquery migrate: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/01/jquery-migrate-1-2-0-released/

Comment: You don't need to include jquery "in" the plugin itself. Just include jquery 1.9.1 and then jquery.autocomplete and it should be fine

Comment: Oh, can not believe my eyes!!! simple paste <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script> below jquery-1.9.1.min.js and all works! so easy solution!

Comment: In the first script above, you are locally-scoping `$` for jQuery but then using the global `jQuery`, which is weird.